# FFTW with qt C++ program crash

Tags: c++, qt, fftw

I try to computing fft at a vector of pixels in time from a list of images with fftw and qt,and repeat this treatement for all pixels of all images; the vector contains [pix1.1 of im1,pix1.1 of im2,...pix1.1 of imN], the problem is when number of images is big the program crashes

```
const int Npoints(widget.imagelistWidget->count());
fftw_complex *in, *out;
in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*Npoints);
out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*Npoints);
double  resfft;
fftw_plan p;

QList<QImage*> imageList;
QImage *imagef ;

for(int k=0;k<liste.size();k++)
{
    imagef = new QImage;
    imagef->load(liste[k]);
    imageList.append(imagef);
}

for(int i=0;i<imagef->width();i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<imagef->height();j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<liste.size();k++)
        {
             imagef  =imageList.at(k);
             QRgb pixelfft=imagef->pixel(i,j);
             double  moyp= qGray(pixelfft);

             in[k][0] = moyp;
             in[k][1] = 0.0;
        }
        p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(Npoints, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
        fftw_execute(p);
        //resultat
        QVector<qreal> realV;
        QVector<qreal> imgV;
        for (int s = 0; s < Npoints; s++) 
        {
            realV.append(out[s][0]);
            imgV.append(out[s][1]);
        }

        for(int l=0;l<liste.size();++l)
        { 
            resfft = sqrt((realV[l] * realV[l]) + (imgV[l] * imgV[l]));
            imagef=imageList.at(l);
            imagef->setPixel(i,j,qGray(qRgb(resfft,resfft,resfft)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: some thoughts: you don't need to call `fftw_plan_dft_1d` each time. A flaw: `imagef` pointer change constantly. Are you sure This is what you want? Are you sure all images have the same size? What is the error you get?

Comment: Which line is it crashing on? Where's the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what @bibi's comment was getting at, but this part looks wrong:

```
for(int i=0;i<imagef->width();i++)
{
for(int j=0;j<imagef->height();j++)
{
    for(int k=0;k<liste.size();k++)
    {

     imagef  =imageList.at(k);
     QRgb pixelfft=imagef->pixel(i,j);
     double  moyp= qGray(pixelfft);

     in[k][0] = moyp;
     in[k][1] = 0.0;
    }
```

Your loops appear to be in the wrong order.  When you call `width` and `height`, you're not calling them on the current image in your inner loop.  What you might want instead is this:

```
for(int k=0;k<liste.size();k++)
{

    //Get the current image from the list
    imagef  = imageList.at(k);

    //Loop over every pixel in the image
    for(int i=0;i<imagef->width();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<imagef->height();j++)
        {
            QRgb pixelfft=imagef->pixel(i,j);
            double  moyp= qGray(pixelfft);

            in[k][0] = moyp;
            in[k][1] = 0.0;
        } 
    }
    /*...*/
```

Comment: no the order is correct because i fill my vector of the pixel in time it means in[k] filled by pixel 1.1 of image1 the pixel 1.1 of image 2 finally pixel 1.1 of imageN, and then pixel 1.2, ...pixel NM so thats why we shoud respect this order.the program run but didn't persist if I click another time in the button to computing fft at list of 2300 it crushs but the first time no